# Changing the column names in pandas using a VLOOKUP from other dataset

Tags: python, pandas, merge, vlookup

Let ee be a pandas dataset with the following columns.

[image: dataset columns]

I want to rename all columns (except Product_Code), to their corresponding values from table4['Period']. E.g., so that the 'M20' column name will now be '2016/09',... 'M53' will now be '2019/06'.

[image: table4]

Answer (score 3):

Create dictionary first and pass it to `rename`:

```
ee = ee.rename(columns=dict(zip(table4['Month'], table4['Period'])))
```

Or pass `Series` with index by `Month` column:

```
ee = ee.rename(columns=table4.set_index('Month')['Period'])
```

**Sample**:

```
table4 = pd.DataFrame(
             {'Month':['M0','M1','M2'],
             'Period':['2015/01','2015/02','2015/03']})

print (table4)
  Month   Period
0    M0  2015/01
1    M1  2015/02
2    M2  2015/03

ee = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Product Code','M0','M2'])

ee = ee.rename(columns=dict(zip(table4['Month'], table4['Period'])))
print (ee)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Product Code, 2015/01, 2015/03]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a sample of the data:

```
ee.columns = ['Product Code','M20','M21']


Month   Period
0   M20 2015/01
1   M21 2015/02

d = dict(zip(ee.Month,ee.Period)) #creates a mapping dictionary
ee.columns=pd.Series(ee.columns).replace(d) #replaces where match found
#['Product Code', '2015/01', '2015/02']
```

Comment: Maybe you want `ee.columns = pd.Series(ee.columns).replace(d)`

Comment: @jezrael that will return a series doesnt it? updated the code now. :)

Comment: if pass it to columns convert to list is not necessary.